# Php & jquery (keyup) filter table

Tags: php, jquery, database, filter

Can somebody please help me with this?I'm trying to filter this table that i've done using phpadmin:

```
        <table align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" id="table">
            <thead>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Hours</th>
                <th>Action</th>

            </thead>

            <?php
            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM home");
            $i=1;
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>".$i."</td>
                            <td>".$row['subject_id']."</td>
                            <td>".$row['name']."</td>
                            <td>".$row['description']."</td>
                            <td>".$row['hours']."</td>
                            <td align='center'>

                            </td>
                    </tr>";
                    $i++;
                }
            ?>
```

I got to filter the table.. showing only the subjects (i mean,for example if i write "calculus" i should get all the rows with that subject)
NOTE:i wanna use the keyup event.

I tried so many times without success..:(. A lot of people use 'div classes' to filter tables and i dont know what to do :(.
I need something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/rFGWZ/

Hope you can help me :(
Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)? It's a great JS library that you can just apply to your table, like so: `$('#table').DataTable();`, and it will automatically add sorting and search.

Comment: i gotta do it in that way :(

Comment: Yes, Datatables is a good solution for this. When applied to a table it does give you a filter for free. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must do it with semi-vanilla JS, I'd pull in jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Add an input:

```
<input id="search" type="text">
```

Finally, write a simple jQuery loop on keyup that adds all rows with matched values to an array and hides the rest:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#search').off('keyup');
        $('#search').on('keyup', function() {
            // Your search term, the value of the input
            var searchTerm = $('#search').val();
            // table rows, array
            var tr = [];

            // Loop through all TD elements
            $('#table').find('td').each(function() {
                var value = $(this).html();
                // if value contains searchterm, add these rows to the array
                if (value.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
                    tr.push($(this).closest('tr'));

                }
            });

            // If search is empty, show all rows
            if ( searchTerm == '') {
                $('tr').show();
            } else {
                // Else, hide all rows except those added to the array
                $('tr').not('thead tr').hide();
                tr.forEach(function(el) {
                    el.show();
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ur4ck2u1/

Comment: Thank you for reply!. Where should i put the jQuery loop of yours?. It seems not to be working properly :/

Comment: It can go anywhere in the code as long as it's under the jQuery link. Did you add classes to the `td` elements?

Comment: Thank you for reply again :), when i put the td class="name" (or anything with a class) it stops working. I put the <input id="search" type="text"> above the </table>

Comment: I altered the JS; you don't need to add classes anymore. This code will hide all rows which do not contain the searchTerm.

Comment: Thanks!, i put the table on the index.php. It is okay to put the jquery in the same page?

Comment: Is not working dude :(, i just paste your code in the bottom of the page (below the </html> and i also put the <input id="search" type="text"> below the </table>. I put the <script type="text/javascript"> src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> below the <head>. What's wrong?

Comment: See the fiddle please. Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: Yeah, it should do that.. but in my pc it is not working pal :(.Am i doing everything right?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is it's not case sensitive... I just added a provision that should ignore case in the search.

Comment: i don't know dude, it is really frustrating.. i think i put all the code in the right way..the program runs but when i write nothing happens :(

Comment: You have a typo on line 5 `<script type="text/javascript"> src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>` there should be no `>` after `text/javascript"`.

Comment: There is an error at line 67.. It says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" using the inspect element.. and mark this line: 
$(document).ready(function() {

Comment: Thank you very very much dude!, it is working properly now :D